# ¿Como pasar el resultado de la variable Fido a un dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente código de sunpy

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from astropy.visualization import time_support

from sunpy import timeseries as ts
from sunpy.net import Fido
from sunpy.net import attrs as a
import pandas as pd 

tstart = "1982-12-01 01:00"
tend = "1982-12-21 24:00"
result = Fido.search(a.Time(tstart, tend), a.Instrument("XRS"))
print(result)
```

que me imprime lo siguiente

```
       Start Time               End Time        Instrument ... Source Provider
----------------------- ----------------------- ---------- ... ------ --------
1982-12-01 00:00:00.000 1982-12-01 23:59:59.999        XRS ...   GOES     SDAC
1982-12-02 00:00:00.000 1982-12-02 23:59:59.999        XRS ...   GOES     SDAC
1982-12-03 00:00:00.000 1982-12-03 23:59:59.999        XRS ...   GOES     SDAC
1982-12-04 00:00:00.000 1982-12-04 23:59:59.999        XRS ...   GOES     SDAC
1982-12-05 00:00:00.000 1982-12-05 23:59:59.999        XRS ...   GOES     SDAC
1982-12-06 00:00:00.000 1982-12-06 23:59:59.999        XRS ...   GOES     SDAC
1982-12-07 00:00:00.000 1982-12-07 23:59:59.999        XRS ...   GOES     SDAC
1982-12-08 00:00:00.000 1982-12-08 23:59:59.999        XRS ...   GOES     SDAC
```

¿Como puedo hacer para pasar result a un dataframe, imprimir todo el dataframe y guardar todo el dataframe en un archivo txt?

Comment: No se sobre el modulo, pero trataré de ayudar: El print indica que son 22 resultados. Que datos querés tomar, todos concatenados en un solo Dataframe, uno solo de esos resultados, etc? Y de casualidad sabés como obtener un objeto tabla (no necesariamente un dataframe) a partir del result?

Comment: @DanteS de la variable result me imprime esos datos, lo que quiero es que esos datos guardados en la variable result convertirlos a un dataframe, para imprimirlos por completo y de allí guardarlos en un csv.

Comment: Primero, te sirve la respuesta que te dió javdromero? Si no, podrías explicarle por que da error y quizá el modifique su respuesta para ayudarte, como hizo hace un momento. Segundo, mi desconocimiento del modulo y leer la documentación me indica que result representa a varias tablas dadas por diversos clientes. O estoy equivocado?

Answer (score 2):

El objeto `sunpy.net.fido_factory.UnifiedResponse` es un poco raro, pero me di cuenta que es un array con sólo una fila, así que si tomas sólo ese row, lo puedes convertir a un `DataFrame`.

```
aux = result[0].to_pandas()
aux
aux.to_csv("result.csv")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]